# Converting .jar which uses pictures into .exe

Tags: java, image, jar, exe, jsmooth

I made a program in Java which uses plenty of pictures(every JButton has one). 
I exported .jar file from my project and converted it to .exe using JSmooth. When I run .exe, everything works fine on my computer, but on other computers there are no pictures on the buttons. How should I provide those pictures with .exe, so everyone can use program, not only my computer?

I searched everywhere, but I can't find my answer, please help!

This is the example of loading images:

```
buttons[index].setIcon(new ImageIcon("cards\\"+(index+1)+".png"));
```

Comment: Where do you store the pictures? And how do you load them for the JButton? (Show the code where you assign each picture to the JButton)

Comment: I edited the original post, now showing the code. My pictures are saved in source folder(cards) I made in eclipse.

Comment: The problem is that the constructor `ImageIcon(String)` loads from a *file*, but not from inside a jar file. In addition to files, Java also has a more abstract concept called "resources". They can be retrieved relative to a Java class and when you put the Java class and images in a jar file, that can still be found. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html

Comment: I tried using getResource method, and everything works in my IDE, but when I export it as jar file, if I try to run it, nothing happens, it won't even open the application. I changed the code to this: `buttons[index].setIcon(new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("resources\\"+(index+1)+".png")))`
When I tried to extract the jar, there was resources folder in it with all the necessary pictures, but program just wouldn't run. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason that you want the jar file to an exe file?
If you mark the Java file as an executable, then you should be able to execute the jar on windows.

It is possible to package the pictures in your Jar. The preferred way is to adept the script where your IDE creates the jar. Which IDE (integrated development environment) do you use?

--- edited ---

The following code you need in your java code:

```
buttons[index].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource((index+1)+".png")));
```

After creating the Jar file, you can open it with an archive program (like winzip or something like that), and you copy the images in the jar file (root).
If you want to do this program automatically, you need to generate an ant file. And adapt this ant file, so that it copies also the png on the fly, more info can be found here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

Comment: Thanks on the answer!
I use Eclipse, how should I make that script?

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I tried your code, but still works only in Eclipse, when I try to run the .jar, it won't even open the program. I unpacked it, and there were already all the pictures in root.

Comment: @HarkoslavBarko, I really need more info. Can you send me an e-mail? You can use: so@ftoc.nl